# Rename multiple symbols at once? (using Roslyn)

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

`Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync` renames one symbol and creates a new `Solution`. If there are 100 symbols to rename - it will need to be called 100 times and there will be 100 complete solutions created (each, from the previous). That’s quite expensive. Is there a way to tell Roslyn to rename a group of symbols and only then create the needed solution?

Comment: I can't find any reference that `RenameSymbolAsync` creates a new solution, can you reference where that is described?

Comment: @RonBeyer: Solutions are immutable.  _Every_ operation creates a new solution.

Comment: @SLaks Guess I haven't played around with Rosyln that much, I was reading [this](http://marcinjuraszek.com/2014/05/solution-wide-rename-from-code-fix-provider-fix-async-method-naming.html), makes sense, I was just wanting to read better documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't currently an API to do it. [We take contributions!](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)

Comment: Thanks. I'll take your word for it :) (As for contributing - I'm just starting with this. But who knows, maybe someday.)

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for this answer (from 2015). I recently tried renaming again, this time just one symbol, and can't seem to do it, even though I tried with the same code I used then (2015). [I posted a question about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61048374/939213).