# How to load solution in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Here is my code that used to work:

```
MSBuildWorkspace msBuild = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution sln = await msBuild.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
```

but now I get:

```
int pr = sln.Projects.Count();//is 1 instead of 2.
```

and:

```
int docs = sln.Projects.First().Documents.Count();//is 0
```

Have they changed it again?

(If it matters, I need the `Solution` in order to iterate over fields etc. and use [Renamer.RenameSymbolAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.rename.renamer.renamesymbolasync?view=roslyn-dotnet) .)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I did it was like so:

```cs
if (!MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered) MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
using (var w = MSBuildWorkspace.Create())
    {
        var sln = await w.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);
    }
```

I believe the `MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults()` is the missing piece here. it ensures the correct msbuild path for your VS version. It might be that your environment path was correct, but then you installed another instance of VS and it's got confused somehow

Comment: I can't test it at the moment but I did, in fact, install a new version of VS after the project was created so it's definitely worth a try. Thanks!

Comment: At this point, use of MSBuildLocator is more or less required since VS2017 now allows multiple installations and some extra complexity. It's a side effect of the fact MSBuild isn't so globally installed anymore.